# How do I call dll inside Java?

Tags: java

How do I call a DLL inside Java program ?

Answer (score 8):

The canonical answer is JNI. However, this is somewhat painful. Other options:

- [Swig](http://www.swig.org/)
- [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)
- [NativeCall](http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/)

Comment: If you also add which one is the latest and best that would have been helpful too. Like initialy it was JNI. Then someone wrote a better solution Swig. Then finding Swig's limitation some wrote JNA which is double faster than Swig etc

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that history.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\yourdllname.dll");
```

if thats your path to your dll