# how to call DLL from java?

Tags: c#, java

how to call DLL from java ? I want to integrate a java application to Windows. Let me take Outlook as an example, I have the Outlook dll, then how to call it ? do we have similar tutorial ?

Comment: google is your friend: one of the first hits:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222092 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771145/how-do-i-call-dll-inside-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java Native Access (JNA) : http://jna.java.net/

http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description

Comment: with jna you dont neeed to write c/c++ code, works only with java! much more easy then jni!

Answer (score 0):

[System.LoadLibrary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) can be used to load the libraries. Check [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535700/loading-dll-in-java-eclipse-jni) for example usage

Comment: This is a *comment*, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is Java Native Interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/index.html

Answer (score 0):

See JNI it aims java to interact with other langages... many links have been posted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **JNI** to call native functions. In your case it  you need to  load Library first in memory using  Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(**PATH_OF_DLL_FILE**)

you can use following link too http://www.equestionanswers.com/dll/java-call-dll-functions.php