# Can I used a dll file in JAVA?

Tags: java

is there a way that functions in a dll file can be called and used in java? I've been searching for a better way to do it and most of the times it pointed me out to using JNI. But my problem with that is, it will be using c++. I'm wondering if there's still another way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: JNI understands C++ just fine. JNA can also make C calls.

Comment: A similar post can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771145/how-do-i-call-dll-inside-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JNI is how it's done.  However, you can speed things up by using a generator tool like:

- [GlueGen](http://jogamp.org/gluegen/www/)
- [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG)

You can also check out Java's Native Access libraries:

- [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) (found [here](https://github.com/twall/jna))